# Altering the message sent by asp:PasswordRecovery email without loosing the password/username

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP PasswordRecovery control on my web application which was sending an email upon a successful password rest containing a short piece of text and then the username and newly reset password.

I needed to make the short piece of text bilingual so I added the following to the code behind:

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Message.IsBodyHtml = false;
    string body = "translated text" + Environment.NewLine + "english text";                            

    e.Message.Body = body;
    e.Message.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subject"];
}
```

What happened then was the translated text came through but the username and password were now missing.

So I tried adding this to my body:

```
string pw = Membership.GetUser(PasswordRecovery1.UserName).GetPassword(PasswordRecovery1.Answer);
            string p = PasswordRecovery1.UserName;
```

And I got this message:

> This Membership Provider has not been configured to support password
>   retrieval.

So I added this to the control:

```
enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
```

But I still got the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Enabling password retrieval is probably *not* what you want, since it changes some significant behavior of the password management.  (Namely, passwords should never be recoverable.  Making them recoverable breaks that.)  If you *do* want to do that, you'll have to do it on the membership provider instead of on the control.  Likely in the `Web.config`.  Conversely, try to examine the value that already exists in `e.Message.Body` before overwriting it.  Maybe you can transform the existing value instead of creating an entirely new one?

Comment: password retrieval is only an option if the password is not hashed. What is the Password Format on your Membership?

Comment: e.Message.Body contains the standard message with the username and password, I just want to get a handle on the username and password and alter the text to my own preference

Comment: Yeh my passwordFormat is Hashed

Comment: It's not well documented but the `PasswordRecovery` control has a `MailDefinition` property. The object that this returns has a property called `BodyFileName` that should be a file that it will read and use as the body of the email. The really hidden feature is that it will do some replacements within that body for `<% UserName %>` and `<% Password %>`. I've not tried this myself but might be worth trying to get this to work instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your Membership is configured to be hashed, then password retrieval is disabled.

> A ConfigurationException will be thrown if enablePasswordRetrieval is set to true and passwordFormat is set to Hashed in the Web.config file for the ASP.NET application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x0c6sfa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If this is the case, you should store the new password in a string, and then save this to the database using the `ChangePassword()` function.

I have this working like the below:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("username"); // or however you want to retrieve the MembershipUser object
string password = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 0); // generate a new password
bool changePasswordSucceeded = user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), password); // reset the password

if(changePasswordSucceeded)
{
    // email logic here
}
```

Comment: That change password function is not working, I'm getting: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: passwordAnswer"

Comment: Then get the Password Answer and use the other `ChangePassword ` overloads. If you want a better answer, please provide the membership provider definition in your web.config. Need that because you haven't provided any of the requirements you have defined for the membership.

Answer (score 0):

I had overcomplicated this massively.

As per Damien's comment you can easily solve this by creating your own `PasswordReset.txt` file, something like:

> Translated Message
>
> Translated word for UserName: <%UserName%> Translated word for
>   Password: <%Password%>
>
> English Message
>
> User Name: <%UserName%> Password: <%Password%>

Then just go to the PasswordRecovery Properties box and point `MailDefinition-BodyFileName` at your file.

As long as you have the tags as per above, the control will swap out the user name and password for you.

No need to mess around with the sending mail event in the code behind.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I was not the one who down voted however it seems terribly insecure to firstly have the password unencrypted and secondly to email the password in plain text? ... Surely a "Password Reset" is more preferable, once the password has been lost simply ensure the user can be verified and then allow them to change it?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul - this is for the password reset functionality where the freshly generated reset password is being sent out to the user - not their original password (which is unrecoverable, because it was hashed)